# How to plot a differential equation?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I solved a differential equation, which gave me the result:

```
 -R[x]*Sqrt[(Q/R[x]) - 1] - (Q/
    2) ArcTan[((2 R[x] - Q)*Sqrt[(Q/R[x]) - 1])/(2 R[x] - 2 Q)] == -a*x
```

where $Q$ is a parameter known. How to plot this?

I tried:

```
f[x] = -R[x]*
   Sqrt[(Q/R[x]) - 1] - (Q/
     2) ArcTan[((2 R[x] - Q)*Sqrt[(Q/R[x]) - 1])/(2 R[x] - 2 Q)]

Plot[f[x] /. Q -> 35 == - x , {x, -80, +80}]
```

but the plot comes out empty.

Is there a way to actually do it, since i guess my attempt is not correct?

Comment: What is `R[x]`? Perhaps it would be best if you gave the differential equation and initial conditions as the starting point.

Comment: R[x] is the function which i wanted to evaluate, i didn't find it using mathematica but integrating per parts by hand, it was a separable ODE

Comment: What is known about parameter `a` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Q,a` are given constants your equation gives an implicit result `x[R]`

```
x = Function[{R}, 
(-R *Sqrt[(Q/R ) - 1] - (Q/2) ArcTan[((2 R - Q)*Sqrt[(Q/R ) - 1])/(2 R - 2Q)])/(-a) ]
```

Which can be plotted with `ParametricPlot[{x[R],R},{R,...}]`

For example `Q->35,a->1`

```
ParametricPlot[{x[R],R}/.{Q->35,a->1} ,{R,0,10}]
```

[image]